# Product of linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Matrix $A=\Bigg| \begin{matrix}
        2 & 0 & 4 \\
        -1 & -1 & -2 \\
        \end{matrix}\Bigg|$ is a matrix of linear mapping $l: R^3\to R^2$ with the respect to bases $B = \{(1,0,0),(0,-1,1),(1,1,1)\}$ and $B' = \{(1,1),(1,2)\}$.

Find $l(1,2,3)$.

My result is $(7,-4)$, but I'm afraid I did some mistake. Could you, please, write your solution?

Comment: Why don't you just check it? How would you go about checking it?

Comment: How am I supposed to check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Write $\,(1,2,3)\,$ as a linear combination of the given basis of $\,\Bbb R^3\,$:

$$(1,2,3)=a(1,0,0)+b(0,-1,1)+c(1,1,1)\,\,\,,\,\,a,b,c,\in\Bbb R$$

For example, $\,c=5/2\,$ ...

(2) Now just calculate

$$A\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}$$

and get your vector...which is going to be given expressed in the given basis of $\,\Bbb R^2\,$, of course.

BTW, your result is correct.

Comment: Addendum, @user50222: So you can use the coefficients of this vector to linearly combine the base vectors from $B'$ to a vector which should be … $(7,-4)$.